# Trying to install oracle xe 18c in linux mint but getting error. Any suggestions?

Tags: database, terminal, rpm, linux-mint, oracle18c

Hello everyone i'm kinda new to linux and trying to install oracle 18c in linux-mint. I have searched this on google and some say it does not support for this distro and some provide a solution to install 18c. If i somehow get this running in my sys, it will be very helpful.

**My Sys info**

shubhro@shubhro-Inspiron-5570:~$ uname -a
Linux shubhro-Inspiron-5570 5.4.0-67-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 18:03:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Below is the error im getting**

```
root@shubhro-Inspiron-5570:/home/shubhro# alien --script oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0’: File exists
unable to mkdir oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0:  at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package.pm line 257.
```

Comment: It seems the directory "oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0" already exist.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic.  Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or  https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Oracle is only supported on Red Hat Linux, Oracle Linux, and SuSE Linux; Mint is based on Ubuntu, which is an entirely different fork of Linux. Any other installation is a hack and the software is not guaranteed to behave as intended. Your best bet would be to use Oracle VirtualBox to run a VM (Oracle has several ready-made ones) with a supported operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got it working by removing the already existing file

sudo rm -rf oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0

if a file exists with that name, the system can't create a directory with the same name, so we have to rm the file for the code to run unaltered.

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to install alien

```
sudo apt install alien libaio1 unixodbc
```

2. convert the .rpm file to .deb with the command

```
sudo alien --script oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

3. install by running the command

```
sudo dpkg -i oracle-database-xe-18c_1.0-2_amd64.deb
```

4. configuration

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure
```

you can see in this link [link](https://lignux.com/instalacion-y-configuracion-de-oracle-database-18c-express-edition/) more details